# Find and delete lines with multiple words in a text file

Tags: linux, bash, find

How can I make a bash script to delete lines if the text file has more than one word?

Comment: an example would be better.

Comment: What do you mean with "delete lines"? So if the file contains more than 1 word, delete what?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like that:

```
#!/bin/bash

exec 3>output

while read -r line; do
  nwords=`echo $line | wc -w`;
  if [ ! "$nwords" -gt 1 ]; then
      echo "$line" >&3;
  fi

done < input

exec 3>&-
```

Then you will have all lines which don't have more than word in output file and you can delete input file than and mv output to input.

Answer (score 0):

I used this, using sed: my txt file is file.txt:

```
one
one two
one two tree for
one two

sed -i.bck '/\(.\+\)\(\s\+\)\(.*\)/d' file.txt
cat file.txt
one
```

Comment: I don't know if it should but it will not work in such case:
one two\n
(spaces)    two
When there are spaces at the beginning

Answer (score 0):

If your words are separated by a "*space*" character you can do it in just one line, with **sed**. Let "*./myfile.txt*" be your file name, then:

```
#!/bin/bash

sed -i "/[^ ][ ]/d" ./myfile.txt
```

The regex replace all space characters preceded by a non space characters, that is the case when you have two words.